# Retrieving single page with slug in apostrophe-headless

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I have been working with `apostrophe-headless` for a while and have worked around the issues of not being able to request pages via the RESTAPI by `slug` in the past. I am about to start a new installation and I want the users to be able to create new pages of various types and edit with the convenience that the standard page type allows within `apostrophe-cms`. That being said, any attempt that I make to set up a filter or change the cursor of `apostrophe-pages` to allow for `slug` filtering fails and I have yet to be able to request a page by anything other than `_id`. I have seen mentions that a page should not be requested by slug, but from an isomorphic react-based app I won't have an `_id` when a user goes directly to a child page. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: child pages will have an `_ancestors` array which should give you id's for all the ancestor pages up the tree, no? Maybe some samples to show how you are setting things up? https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless#accessing-ancestor-pages

Comment: Yes, but how would the app know what request to make when only given a url? I don't want to make multiple/unneeded requests to the API.

Comment: I have currently created a fork of apostrophe-headless that serves my needs. I am completely open to changes and suggestions.
https://github.com/blaineo/apostrophe-headless